# PHP dynamic include content approaches

Tags: php, dynamic, include

I'd like to have the same header and footer on every page only with different contents using PHP. What is the best approach to do this?

I know of these two popular ones, but don't know which of them (or maybe some others) to choose:

### 1. Include header and footer on every page

Into every page like *contact.php*, *about.php*, etc. you have to include header on top of the page and footer on the bottom. The content then goes between the too. For example *contact.php* would look like this:

```
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
<?php include("footer.php"); ?>
```

When you want to do request, you just type `example.com/contact.php`

### 2. index.php?page=xyz

In pages like *contact.php*, *about.php*, etc. you store only the actual content. Then you have *index.php* with some parameter (e.g. page) by which you specify the content to be included. For example the *contact.php* file would look like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
```

And the *index.php* file like this (this is simplified version):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include(some_parser_function($_GET["page"].".php")); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when you do request for `index.php?page=contact` it will show you *index.php* and between the opening and closing `body` tags the content from *contact.php*.

The first approach seems to me a bit unpractical, because you have to write the include functions into every page. In the second approach, if you want to have nice URLs like `example.com/contact.php` or just `example.com/contact`, you need to do apache mod_rewriting...

**Which one of those (and others) approaches is better / more popular and why?**

Thanks.

Comment: Well from a performance standpoint #2 has 1 include, vs 2 includes, but I don't know that it would really matter in the grand scheme of things. I used to use #2 extensively when I first started learning PHP and it was very convenient to add new pages inside of the design, but if I wanted to do something different then I would have to edit the template and maintain it separately. In the end which one you use is dependent on your needs.

Comment: I also started with the #2, but now I think the #1 looks better. I would use the #1 if I had a few pages, but the more pages I have, the more includes I would have to type...:)

Comment: a general rule, you should not trust user input. First approach is the way to go!

Comment: I can do this with ignoring all user inputs except the ones that contains chars/numbers with mod_rewrite and regex...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is much better for templating. You can also use Rewrite to make this appear without have ?page=pagename at the end of the url. Also depending on how many pages you have on your site it is kind of a pain to have to do the two includes on every single file.

However if I were you I would look into using ob_start() ob_get_contents() and ob_flush(). Then you can actually run all the code on the included file before you start outputting html.

Here is an example:

```
ob_start();
include("{$page_name}.php");
$page_contents = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

ob_start();
include("templates/standard.php");
$full_html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo $full_html;
```

This way you can easily create multiple templates to be used at any point. A template file would look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php echo $page_contents; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I started using this method a while ago and love it. I used to use your option 1 and it is very limiting and can be a pain.

Comment: Maybe it wasn't available in 2012: with `ob_get_clean()` you can get buffer contents and delete the buffer in a single call. It would become: `$page_contents = ob_get_clean();` .. done!

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid dynamic includes if at all possible. It opens up a security hole unless you sanitize the variable that is coming from an external source, i.e. a GET parameter in your case. You could take an approach like Model-View-Controller frameworks do. They have code that essentially puts the output from templates into the layout.

Comment: I check every URL with RewriteRule and only if it contains letters and numbers I'll pass it to the PHP... I think the MVC approach is a little complicated for what I need.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm just suggesting a framework because they come with boilerplate code for handling routing, layouts, templates, etc. May come in handy for larger projects but might be more trouble than it's worth for really small projects.

Answer (score 0):

In general, the great advantage of the 2 approach is the verification/insertion. If you take the first approach, you will have to do all the verifications/insertions again and again. And if you ever have to change/add/remove something, you will have to change all the pages. That is quite annoying. I usually prefer the 2nd approach, since you can centralize everything and avoid repeating the same instructions all around.

But that depends a lot on your website too.

I'll give you an example: I once did a site that had 2 main divisions.

In this case I did 2 different pages of the 2nd approach.

(when I'm talking about verifications, I mean things like verifying all the SESSION variables, if the user is logged, if he is ADM etc etc)

Comment: Can't you just put SESSION controlling in header.php?